# How to select from table with conditions from other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this mysql setup:

```
*words* table
+----+-----------+
| id |   word    |
+----+-----------+
| 1  |  curse1   |
| 2  |  curse2   |
| 3  | niceWord1 |

*Category* table
+----+-----------+
| id |    name   |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | niceWords |
| 2  | badWords  |

*link* table
+----+--------+-------+
| id | wordID | catID |
+----+-----------+----+
| 1  |    1   |   2   |
| 2  |    2   |   2   |
| 3  |    3   |   1   |
```

I want to make a MySQL SELECT where I say I want to select all bad words using the link table
So i'll get something like this output:

```
+----------+------------+---------------+
| words.id | words.word | Category.name |
+----------+------------+---------------+
|    1     |  curse1    |   badWords    |
|    2     |  curse2    |   badWords    |
```

I think I need to use JOIN of some kind, im not so good at SQL.

Pastebin with the same: http://pastebin.com/ML684RRA

Comment: yes  join, at least make an attempt

Comment: just as a FYI it is really frowned on when you post the same question in multiple places. generally you should make an attempt and then post that asking for fixes/help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select words.id, words.word, Category.name
from words
join link on link.wordid = words.id
join category on category.id = link.catid
where category.name = 'badWords'
```

Answer (score 1):

just join the tables through relevant ID's and then filter out the good words by using a WHERE the bad word ID = 2... i also added aliases to the table names because its a good practice to have.

```
SELECT
    w.word,
    c.name,
    c.id
FROM words w
JOIN link l on l.wordID = w.id
JOIN Category c on c.id = l.catID
WHERE c.id = 2
```